# How many blue coins are in each area of Super Mario Sunshine?

Tags: super-mario-sunshine

How many blue coins are in each area of Super Mario Sunshine? Is there an indicator or tally of how many blue coins are remaining in each area, and overall in the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Delfino Airstrip: 1
- Delfino Plaza: 19
- Bianco Hills, Gelato Beach, Ricco Harbor, Pinna Park, Noki Bay, Sirena Beach, Pianta Village: 30
- Corona Mountain: 10

Total of 240. Sorry, no way to find out how many are left, but you can see how many blue coins you have collected in an area by pressing the Z button and selecting a level on the map. The amount of blue coins collected in that area is shown at the bottom right. Unfortunately, Delfino Plaza does not show this tally.

Source(s)

- http://www.ign.com/faqs/2002/super-mario-sunshine-blue-coins-faq-374577

Comment: Thanks! After futzing around, I did finally notice that the game shows a tally of blue coins you have gotten in an area if you look in the map (Z button). Using the totals you provided, I can at least know how many are remaining. I've added this to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Huh, didn't notice. Good catch and glad to be help.